# Merge Sorting Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

i have been solving the problem related to merge sorting but dont know what is the problem in my program so can you please look on it?

the question was to give a unsorted array and it will provide sorted without changing the original array.
please let me know where is my mistake

```
public static int []  mergeSort(int[] in){

        int [] temp = in.clone();

        if (temp.length <= 1){

            }


        else{
            int [] first = new int[temp.length/2];
            int [] second = new int [temp.length - first.length];

            for (int i=0; i<first.length; i++){
                first[i] = temp[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < second.length; i++){
                second[i] = temp[first.length+i];
            }

            mergeSort(first);
            mergeSort(second);
            merg(first,second,temp);

        }

    return temp;
    }
    public static void merg(int [] first, int[] second, int []newTemp){


        int i =0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while(i <first.length && j < second.length ){

            if(first[i] <=second[j]){

                newTemp[k] = first[i];
                i++;
            }
            else{
                newTemp[k] = second[j];
                j++;

            }
            k++;

        }
        while (i < first.length){
            newTemp[k] = first[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j < second.length){
            newTemp[k]= second[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Jens it dosent effect any thing to my array. so dont know how to specify the problem hope you understand. and i am new to programming

Comment: Where are you calling `mergeSort()`?  The problem could be that you are not changing the items in the original array, you are passing in an array, then cloning it, then returning the clone.

Comment: exactly i am calling it in main where i pass the array but it suppose to return me a new sorted array but its not i am calling it like this

Comment: mergeSort(n);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));

Comment: Try doing something with the result of calling `mergeSort()`, and maybe have `merg()` return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are cloning the array and each time you call the mergeSort() function, it again clones the array. It needs to be cloned only the first time function is called.

Here is the complete solution for your problem. You should call the first mergeSort() function.

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] in) {
    return mergeSort(in, 0);
}

public static int[] mergeSort(int[] in, int number_of_times_called) {

    int[] temp;
    if (number_of_times_called == 0)
        temp = in.clone();
    else
        temp = in

    if (temp.length <= 1){
        return temp;
    }


    else{
        int [] first = new int[temp.length/2];
        int [] second = new int [temp.length - first.length];

        for (int i=0; i<first.length; i++){
            first[i] = temp[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < second.length; i++){
            second[i] = temp[first.length+i];
        }

        mergeSort(first);
        mergeSort(second);
        merg(first,second,temp);

    }

    return temp;
}

public static void merg(int [] first, int[] second, int []newTemp){


    int i =0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while(i <first.length && j < second.length ){

        if(first[i] <=second[j]){

            newTemp[k] = first[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            newTemp[k] = second[j];
            j++;

        }
        k++;

    }
    while (i < first.length){
        newTemp[k] = first[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j < second.length){
        newTemp[k]= second[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

}
```